# How get TIMEDIFF of each row's date field with the closest previous date row without a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to calculate the TIMEDIFF between a row and the row whose field `dateCompleted` is the last one just before this one and then get the value as `timeSinceLast`.

I can do this easily as a subquery but it's very slow. (About 12-15 times slower than a straight query on the table for just the rows).

```
#Very slow
Select a.*, TIMDIFF(a.dateCompleted, (SELECT a2.dateCompleted FROM action a2 WHERE a2.dateCompleted < a.dateCompleted ORDER BY a2.dateCompleted DESC LIMIT 1)) as timeSinceLast
FROM action a;
```

I tried doing it as a join with itself but couldn't figure out how to get that work as I don't know how to do a `LIMIT 1` on the join table and not the query as a whole.

```
#How limit the join table only?
SELECT a.*, TIMEDIFF(a.dateCompleted, a2.dateCompleted)
FROM action a
LEFT JOIN action a2 on a2.dateCompleted < a.dateCompleted 
LIMIT 1;
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

EDIT: Schema and data

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03b5c/3

```
create table Actions
( 
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   dateCompleted datetime not null
);


#Notice, they can come out of order.
#   The third one would affect the first one in my query as
#   it's the first completed date right after the first

insert into Actions (dateCompleted)
values ("2016-05-06 12:11:01");

insert into Actions (dateCompleted)
values ("2016-05-06 12:11:03");

insert into Actions (dateCompleted)
values ("2016-05-06 12:11:02");

insert into Actions (dateCompleted)
values ("2016-05-06 12:11:05");

insert into Actions (dateCompleted)
values ("2016-05-06 12:11:04");
```

Result (order by dateCompleted):

```
id  dateCompleted          timeSinceLast
 1, "2016-05-06 12:11:01", null
 3, "2016-05-06 12:11:02", 1
 2, "2016-05-06 12:11:03", 1
 5, "2016-05-06 12:11:04", 1
 4, "2016-05-06 12:11:05", 1
```

(In this simple example, they all had a one second time since the next one)

Comment: maybe the ideas here http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/04/12/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=1 will help you

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not at a computer right now, but I'll add that soon.

Comment: @Strawberry I created a sqlfiddle but it doesn't seem to work. Please see my edits here with some sql code and schema.

Comment: @Strawberry I got a SQLFiddle working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03b5c/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , MIN(TIMEDIFF(x.datecompleted,y.datecompleted)) 
  FROM actions x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN actions y 
    ON y.datecompleted < x.datecompleted 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id 
 ORDER 
    BY x.datecompleted;
```

...or faster...

```
SELECT x.*
     , TIMEDIFF(datecompleted,@prev)
     , @prev:=datecompleted 
  FROM actions x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY datecompleted;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's amazing! Sorry to ask this, but is it also possible in the other direction? I mean, get the `timediff` with the *next* row instead of the previous row?

Comment: Yes. See if you can figure that out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to but not sure since your current solution with variables is storing the value from the previous row. I'm not sure how to forward-look without using cursors.

Comment: Well, here's a clue: the first query looks backwards by looking at y's which are before x's. The second query looks backward by ordering the dataset in ascending order.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I need to get my brain working the same as yours. I'm definitely not employing the KISS method enough. OK, I can do this by changing the order to DESC in which case the "y" is now "z" to the "x" value.